# How do I limit characters and then unlimit then on hover using css scale?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

So, I have a roundish card that my client don't want to get rid off, but the dynamic text will always be larger than the card itself. I have to limit the characters at first and then show the full text on hover and he want's me to zoom in the card so it can be larger to fit the text. How do I do that? I've been trying scale and width with ch, but on hover I cannot change the width since it only zooms in.

I'm using Angular 9, Typescript and Scss.

```
.model-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 65rem;
    height: 55vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
  
    .model-card {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 10px 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 16rem;
      height: 5rem;
      border-radius: 50px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
      cursor: pointer;
  
      .text {
        width: 13rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 16px;
  
        .name {
          font-size: 15px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #626c75;
          margin: 0px;
          width: 100%;
        }
  
        .description {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: #dce1e7;
          margin: 0px;
          width: 17ch;
          overflow: hidden;
          white-space: nowrap;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
      }
  
      .icon-container {
        width: 5rem;
        height: 5rem;
  
        img {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
      }
  
      &:hover,
      &.active {
        transform: scale(1.2);
        .name,
        .description {
          width: 60ch;
          color: white;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u also share the html

Comment: Imho scaling the entire card is kind of funky idea... But if that's the route  you have to do then scaling the entire card on `:hover` will also scale the entire contents. In that light maybe, on `:hover` you could decrease `font-size` in relation to scale?

Comment: @Joosep.P +1 for the honest opinion. I think OP should reconsider a different design. "Zoom in the card" doesn't guarantee that all the dynamic text will have enough space to display itself. A much simpler approach is to ellipse the text and place an icon next to it. When the user hovers over that icon, we can do a popover that displays the entire text.

Comment: I cannot reconsider a different design cause I've already showed my ideas to the client and he was NOT happy about changing this horrific card. Thank you all for the ideas, I've never done something like it, so i'm kinda lost. I'm guessing css doesn't behave the same way when I'm using scale, that's why is being difficult